Is there any way C# to deserialize a JSON string of one class into another class?
My program has a class with many properties that store all the settings and information for a user's project, like this:
Class Config{
    public bool EnableYoutube { get; set; }= true;
    public bool EnableFacebook { get; set; }= true;
}

When the user saves, I serialize this class to JSON and save it to a text file. Conversely, when the user loads a project, I read the text file and deserialize the JSON to restore the project's settings and information.
Now I have a tricky problem: when I update the software, I may add some features and need to modify or add new properties to this class, like this:
Class Config{
    public bool EnableYoutube { get; set; }= true;
    
    public bool EnableTiktok { get; set; }= true;
}

When the user updates the software and then loads a project, the deserialization of this JSON fails because the structure of the two classes has changed.
I may use a database later, but now the project schedule is tight and I can't make too big a switch. Maybe there are better ways to save settings in a plain text file? How can I solve this problem?
After running some tests, I figured out the problem. Since I need to use AOT compilation, I have to use source generation in System.Text.Json. The code for this part is shown below:
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Config))]

if (objectType == typeof(Config))
{
    option = allContext.Default.Config;
}

JsonTypeInfo? option = getOption(objectType);

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(input!, option);

However, when I modify the class used for saving information, the old user save file does not match any items in the source generation, which causes an error when deserializing the JSON: "JsonTypeInfo? option equals null, which may mean that an unspecified structure cannot be JSON serialized." This seems to mean that I need to save all versions of the project's save classes in source generation, which is a bit too much.

this is more of an organizational than a programming question. You need to ask yourself how you would migrate the config. So what should happen if user loads an old config into new software? Are the new settings automatically set to whatever value? Or should the config be changed by user?

What are you using to do the serialization? System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json both have NullValueHandling you should research.

How does the deserialisation fail? Do you get an error? Show us the code that does that.. Here's some example code showing there is no error https://dotnetfiddle.net/BhX7dX

Since this is effectively an Application File Format, you should have included a Version Field. Now that the damage is done, I'd recommend to include a Version Field and consider any configuration missing that field "legacy" (the version you had before your current changes). Then you can keep your model backwards-compatible and know which fields to expect having no value set. How to deal with that is on another page.

We're going to need more. Both System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json deserialize to the new class correctly without throwing errors. We need an example that shows the actual problem you're having, as briefly as possible.

After running some tests, I figured out the problem. Since I need to use AOT compilation, I have to use source generation in System.Text.Json. However, when I modify the class used for saving information, the old user save file does not match any items in the source generation, which causes an error when deserializing the JSON: "JsonTypeInfo? option equals null, which may mean that an unspecified structure cannot be JSON serialized." This seems to mean that I need to save all versions of the project's save classes in source generation, which is a bit too much.

This will depend on what changes you make and how you configure the serializer.
System.text.json should be fairly tolerant by default, if there are extra properties they should simply be ignored. As far as I can see your example should just work. But it is a very good idea to write unit tests for things like this:
public class Config1
{
    public bool EnableYoutube { get; set; } = true;
    public bool EnableFacebook { get; set; } = true;
}
public class Config2
{
    public bool EnableYoutube { get; set; } = true;
    public bool EnableTiktok { get; set; } = true;
}
[Test]
public void SerializeTest()
{
    var sut = new Config1() { };
    var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sut);
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Config2>(str));
}

A few recommendations:

A version number and other metadata of the format may be useful. Note that this should probably not be part of the serialized data, but may, for example, be part of the file name or extension.
Use dedicated classes that is only used for serialization, this can allow you to maintain multiple versions of your config class if you make larger structural changes, and write custom code to do the conversion to the latest format. Such types are sometimes called "data transfer objects", i.e. "ConfigDTO" do differentiate them from classes containing logic.
Use attributes, like [JsonRequired] or [JsonPropertyName(...)] to tell the serializer how to handle properties.
Make sure to have default values for non-required properties.
You can use a zip archive to store multiple pieces of data in a single file. This can help with "project"-type files containing heterogeneous data, while still allowing for fairly easy debugging.

Consider both backward compatibility (i.e new software loading old project) and forward compatibility (i.e. old software loading newer project). It is not uncommon to simply display an error if trying to load a file from a newer version.
Storing settings in a plain text-file would not in itself solve the backwards compatibility problem, nor would a database. Regardless of the way you store data you need to keep in mind, and test, backward and/or forward compatibility. The best approach will depend on the exact use case.

After running some tests, I figured out the problem. Since I need to use AOT compilation, I have to use source generation in System.Text.Json. However, when I modify the class used for saving information, the old user save file does not match any items in the source generation, which causes an error when deserializing the JSON: "JsonTypeInfo? option equals null, which may mean that an unspecified structure cannot be JSON serialized."
This seems to mean that I need to save all versions of the project's save classes in source generation, which is a bit too much.

@IronEater I have not used AOT or source generation, so I might not be of much help in that regard. But are you per chance using polymorphic serialization? Serializing a derived type will obviously not allow deserialization in a version that type do not exist.
